# SQL Server : COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE) )

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case, distinct

I need to count number of currencies and if there are more than two it need to be `USD`. It can be `GBP`, or anything else but if it's more than 1 then need to be `USD`.

Well, my query should looks like this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (case ft.currency_name > 1 then 'USD' end)) as  Currency_Name
FROM 
   fundtable ft
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ft.Currency_Name,
    (CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT ft.Currency_Name)> 1 THEN 'USD' 
        ELSE ft.Currency_Name END) Currency_Name
FROM 
    fundtable ft
GROUP BY 
    ft.Currency_Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
select case when count(distinct ft.[currency_name]) > 1 then 'USD'
            else ft.[currency_name]
        end as [Currency_Name]
from [fundtable] ft
group by ft.[currency_name]
```